# What type of Pokémon coins are these?

Tags: pokemon

[image]

[image]

I have no idea where they came from or what they are, if any one knows I would greatly appreciate an answer.

Comment: Some kind of bottle cap?

Comment: Pogs slammers, maybe?  Do they feel somewhat weighty and sturdy for their size?

Comment: No, they are actually quite light. Probably made out of aluminum. I have not found anything about them online yet, so they might have just been some sort of promotional item, I dont know but maybe something like the toy you would get with a mc donald’s meal

Comment: I found [some](https://www.ebay.com/itm/POKEMON-BATTLE-COIN-CAPS-LOT-X45-NEO-JAPAN-POCKET-MONSTERS-POGS-USED-RARE/273823318101) being sold as "*POKEMON BATTLE COIN CAPS LOT X45 NEO JAPAN POCKET MONSTERS POGS USED RARE*". This keyword soup is not that useful --they don't appear to be Pokemon Battle Coins or Pogs-- but maybe the seller can help you identify them

Answer (score 2):

These are Metal Pokémon Tazos from Taiwan.

They were distributed as promotional items in Frito-Lays or Smiths products, more specifically, I believe these came in Cheetos packets.

They came in 3 sizes, but these seem to be the small variant.